# Android data binding - 'No resource identifier found for attribute'

Tags: android, data-binding

My layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      app:fontName="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My binding adapter method:

```
public class FontBinding {

  @BindingAdapter("bind:fontName")
  public static void setFontName(TextView view, @NonNull String fontName) {
    String fontPath = "/fonts/" + fontName;

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(), fontPath);

    view.setTypeface(typeface);
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Error:(8) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fontName' in package 'com.example.databindingproject'
```

Followed the tutorial from https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html . 
Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to add a custom font resource for your app to use?

Comment: Where and how setFontName is called?

Comment: Not important right now if I'm trying a custom font or not. Just wanting to define a custom attribute via the android data binding mechanism. @Angudroid - check the link from the post - the doc says the method will be called by the system.

Comment: @marius, okay, so when you breakpoint at "String fontPath" what is the fontName value ?

Comment: it's a compile time error. so no breakpoints :)

Comment: Rebuilding the project fixed this error in my case

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You must use the data binding syntax. It should be:

```
<TextView
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      app:fontName='@{"Roboto-Regular.ttf"}'
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting another error as well: Error:(24, 21) No resource type specified (at 'fontName' with value '@{"Roboto-Regular.ttf"}'). Is there any (github) example project showcasing this?

Comment: It appears as if your BindingAdapter method is not being found. I'm not sure why that would be. Does other data binding work for you?

Comment: Yep - the data binding variables work fine. Tried this in a new project, with just the @BindingAdapter and it gives the same error.

Comment: I just tried it exactly as you stated and the only error I get is that it can't find the font asset Roboto-Regular.ttf (which I didn't add). It looks to me that your data binding configuration isn't set up properly. You have `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'` in your app/build.gradle, and `classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"` in buildscript.dependencies in your project's build.gradle, right?

Comment: Yep. Pushed sample to https://github.com/marius-bardan/DataBinding-Example . Am I missing something?

Comment: You must use a data binding layout. The root tag must be <layout> or else the data binding system won't know that it should parse your layout file.

Comment: Great. Now compile works, but the static method never gets called. Updated sample. Still not sure what's the beef with the 'bind:' namespace. Could that be it?

Comment: You must inflate with DataBinding. In onCreate, use `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)` instead of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Comment: That's the missing piece! Thanks

Comment: I suggest you use the following notation: `app:fontName="@{\`Roboto-Regular.ttf\`}"` (using back quotes

Comment: Damn this saved the life!! Thank you! So When you get declare attributes, in `xml ` data has to be provided in Binding format. `@{your_data_here}`

Answer (score 16):

This same error can also happen if you forget the closing curly brace:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass **dp/px** value to @BindingAdapter - remember to wrap it with a binding syntax i.e. **"@{  }"**

You need to use dimens.xml to pass the value:

`app:compoundDrawableSize="@{@dimen/icon_size}"`

Accompanying binding adapter enabling you to set copound drawable size for a TextView would look like the following:

```
/**
 * Binding adapter to set the size of TextView's compound drawable
 *
 * Usage:
 * <TextView   [...]
 *       android:drawableLeft="@{@drawable/ic_myicon}"
 *       app:compoundDrawableSize="@{@dimen/icon_size}"
 *  />
 */
@BindingAdapter("bind:compoundDrawableSize", "android:drawableLeft", "android:drawableStart",
        "android:drawableRight", "android:drawableEnd", requireAll = false)
fun TextView.setCompoundDrawableSize(px: Float, @IntegerRes drawableLeft: Drawable?, @IntegerRes drawableStart: Drawable?,
                                     @IntegerRes drawableRight: Drawable?, @IntegerRes drawableEnd: Drawable?) {
    val compoundDrawableLeft = drawableLeft ?: drawableStart
    val compoundDrawableRight = drawableRight ?: drawableEnd
    compoundDrawableLeft?.setBounds(0, 0, px.toInt(), px.toInt())
    compoundDrawableRight?.setBounds(0, 0, px.toInt(), px.toInt())
    this.setCompoundDrawables(compoundDrawableLeft, null, compoundDrawableRight, null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start)To configure your app to use data binding, add the dataBinding element to your build.gradle file in the app module, as shown in the following example:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late I did all the answers but it didn't work for me, and when I added this code:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

in build.gradle in the app-level folder, inside the android tag like below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.development.allanproject"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

My issue was fixed.